# Can't install python because of zypper conflict

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, python

I have a virtual machine I just set up. I'm running a completely fresh install of OpenSUSE (with online updates from `yast`). At the terminal I tried to run `python`:

```
$ python
bash: python: command not found
```

I tried:

```
$ python --version
bash: python: command not found
```

So then I tried:

```
$ zypper install python

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64 
conflicts with python provided by python-2.7.3-10.1.1x86_64
```

The terminal then offers two solutions, to either uninstall the minimal base conflicts business or to not install python. I don't want to uninstall anything because I don't know what it will. I suppose I could if I had a better understanding of it, but perhaps there is a problem someone else can see here?

---

**Edit**: Don't know if this will help, but I did not install any GUI on my virtual machine.

Comment: Perhaps python isn't in your path (that would be strange but not impossible). In my distro, the binary is installed as `/usr/bin/python`. To make an exhaustive search for it, you can try `find -executable -name "python"`.

Comment: Oops sorry. `find / -executable -name "python"`.

Comment: @lgeorget Thank you for your answer. my /usr/bin/ directory does not contain python. The find command does not yield anything either.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the problem now. In fact, python indeed isn't installed yet. The message from zypper tells you that installing would conflict with `patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64` which is already installed. I'm afraid I can't help you, I'm not used to the SUSE distribution so I can't tell if you can safely uninstall `patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you remove `patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64` and then install `python-2.7.3-10.1.1x86_64`?

Note that a "better" find command might be:

```
$ find /  -executable -regex ".*python.*"
```

or

```
find / -executable -name 'python*'"
```

This should give you all instances of *bin*python* and thus you can see where it is installed.    I suspect that your PATH is badly set up.

Comment: If `find / -executable -name "python"` doesn't find out anything, I'm not sure `locate python` will...

Comment: What about `/usr/bin/python2.7`?  Yes, it would be a silly thing to install Python this way but I have seen it done before...

Comment: You're right! Let's `find / -executable -name 'python*'"` then.

Comment: @lgeorget: That works ^_~

Comment: But in fact, my opinion is that python is not installed and that the error message is confusing because the blocking package is not python but `patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64`.

Comment: @lgeorget That find command got me this: /usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh

Comment: @jeff-fabiny. This doen't seem related to the python binary. I guess it's a script used by rpm to check or build the list of dependencies of python packages to be installed. Again, just guessing, I'm not a SUSE expert.

Comment: I just did that and it seems to be working right. I think base conflicts might just be a list of minimal packages required by OpenSUSE and Python isn't one of them. Hopefully things don't break down the road!